# Usage of the indefinite article with numbers

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

The indefinite article is generally not used with numbers, but sometimes it is. Here is an example:

> The gymnast had one of the highest scores of the Olympics with a 7.600 on floor exercise.

Why is 'a' used there before the score?

Comment: Understand it as *...with a (score of) 7.600...*

Answer (score 2):

I think that's because 7.600 isn't intended as an amount of something. If it had been "7.600 points" you shouldn't have used the article.